# How can I link 2 existing models in my laravel code?

Tags: laravel

I have two models customer and orders. They are already fecthed separately

```
$customers = customer::all();

$orders = orders::all();
```

customerID=1 has orderID : 1, 2,4 customerID=2 has orderID : 3,5,9

They are related (hasMany, belongsTo) but the problem is inside my for a certain reason they are separated but I want to send them as response in API using  toJson or ToArray as one data having the orders nested to their correct customers.

How can I achieve that linking to have at the end one variable $customersWithOrders that should be transformed to JSON ?

I am using laravel 5.5

Comment: Don't fetch them separately... Use relationships; a `Customer` should have mulitple `Order` records, and you should have a relationship to reflect this. Then, you can do `$customers = Customer::with('orders')->get();` (note: models are `TitleCase` and singular: `Customer` and `Order`, not `customer` and `orders`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the context is. Defining relationships as other answers mentioned is a good solution.

In addition, I recently read a [pretty good article](https://reinink.ca/articles/optimizing-circular-relationships-in-laravel) about this specific scenario.

So you can also do something like this, if you have already retrieved customers and orders:

```
$customers = Customer::all();
$orders = Order::all();

return $customers->each(function ($customers) use ($orders) {
    $customer->setRelation('orders', $orders->where('customer_id', $customer->id));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test it, I  hope $orders->where('customer_id',$customer->id) does make a call to the database. I want everything to be done with the data in memory.  I read one of his article also he is really pulling our attention on very important things that we tend to ignore sometimes: https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries

Comment: It surely doesn’t access the db again.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a relation you just use it. For example, in model `Customer.php`:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

Then you'd get customer orders by calling `$customer->orders`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have defined relations, you can simply fetch data with eager loading

```
// in customer model
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(orders::class, 'orderID');
}

// in controller
$customersWithOrders = customer::with('orders')->get();
return response()->json(['customersWithOrders' => $customersWithOrders]);

// in js
for (let customer in response.customersWithOrders){
    let orders = customer.orders
}
```